# Optimising Func Declaration Location

Tags: c#, optimization, delegates, func

I have two `Func<T,T2>` objects that will be used in a method that will be called repeatedly (although this method will only be called from this one location), would it be more efficient to declare the `Func`s in the parent function (so that they only have to be instantiated once)and pass them to the child or to put them inside the child function (so that they are closer to the usage).

I don't know much about the inner workings of the `Func` class or the `C#` compiler's optimization algorithm.

For illustration purposes:

Situation 1:

```
    static void ThreadWorker(ref int current, ref int count)
    {
        bool isFinished = false;
        while (!isFinished)
        {
            int workingValue = current++;
            if (workingValue > TARGET)
            {
                isFinished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (EightyNineChain(workingValue))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private static bool EightyNineChain(int value)
    {
        Func<int, int[]> getDigits = v => v.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()).ToArray();
        Func<int[], int> getDigitSquareSum = x => (int)x.Select(d => Math.Pow(d, 2)).Sum();
        //More code here
        return result;
    }
```

And Situation 2:

```
    static void ThreadWorker(ref int current, ref int count)
    {
        Func<int, int[]> getDigits = v => v.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()).ToArray();
        Func<int[], int> getDigitSquareSum = x => (int)x.Select(d => Math.Pow(d, 2)).Sum();
        bool isFinished = false;
        while (!isFinished)
        {
            int workingValue = current++;
            if (workingValue > TARGET)
            {
                isFinished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (EightyNineChain(workingValue, getDigits, getDigitSquareSum))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private static bool EightyNineChain(int value, Func<int,int[]> getDigits, Func<int[],int> getDigitSquareSum)
    {

        //More code here
        return result;
    }
```

To me, situation 1 makes the code cleaner as the `Func`s are declared closer to where they're used and as such it makes it more readable. However, logic tells me that situation 2 ought to be faster and more efficient.

Comment: Is there a reason why these are dynamic `Func<>`s at all? Why not make them regular functions?

Comment: Honestly, in this particular context they could be regular functions and now you mention it I've changed them (was just being lazy) but I believe my question could still yield a useful answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the best approach here is to use C# 7's local functions.

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test1(1));
            Console.WriteLine(test2(1));

            Func<int, int[]> getDigits = v => v.ToString().Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
            Func<int[], int> getDigitSquareSum = x => (int)x.Select(d => Math.Pow(d, 2)).Sum();

            Console.WriteLine(test3(1, getDigits, getDigitSquareSum));
        }

        static int test1(int value) // Use local Func<>
        {
            Func<int, int[]> getDigits = v => v.ToString().Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
            Func<int[], int> getDigitSquareSum = x => (int)x.Select(d => Math.Pow(d, 2)).Sum();

            var a = getDigits(value);
            var b = getDigitSquareSum(a);

            return b;
        }

        static int test2(int value) // Use local function.
        {
            int[] digits(int v) => v.ToString().Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
            int digitSquareSum(int[] x) => (int) x.Select(d => Math.Pow(d, 2)).Sum();

            var a = digits(value);
            var b = digitSquareSum(a);

            return b;
        }

        // Pass in Func<>
        static int test3(int value, Func<int, int[]> getDigits, Func<int[], int> getDigitSquareSum)
        {
            var a = getDigits(value);
            var b = getDigitSquareSum(a);

            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

This is converted to the following IL code:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApp1.Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static void Main () cil managed 
    {
        .entrypoint
        .locals init (
            [0] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]> getDigits,
            [1] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32> getDigitSquareSum
        )

        IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0001: call int32 ConsoleApp1.Program::test1(int32)
        IL_0006: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
        IL_000b: ldc.i4.1
        IL_000c: call int32 ConsoleApp1.Program::test2(int32)
        IL_0011: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
        IL_0016: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__0_0'
        IL_001b: dup
        IL_001c: brtrue.s IL_0035

        IL_001e: pop
        IL_001f: ldsfld class ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c' ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9'
        IL_0024: ldftn instance int32[] ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<Main>b__0_0'(int32)
        IL_002a: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]>::.ctor(object,  native int)
        IL_002f: dup
        IL_0030: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__0_0'

        IL_0035: stloc.0
        IL_0036: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__0_1'
        IL_003b: dup
        IL_003c: brtrue.s IL_0055

        IL_003e: pop
        IL_003f: ldsfld class ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c' ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9'
        IL_0044: ldftn instance int32 ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<Main>b__0_1'(int32[])
        IL_004a: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32>::.ctor(object,  native int)
        IL_004f: dup
        IL_0050: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__0_1'

        IL_0055: stloc.1
        IL_0056: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0057: ldloc.0
        IL_0058: ldloc.1
        IL_0059: call int32 ConsoleApp1.Program::test3(int32,  class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]>,  class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32>)
        IL_005e: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
        IL_0063: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static int32 test1 (
            int32 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .locals init (
            [0] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]> getDigits,
            [1] int32[] a
        )

        IL_0000: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__1_0'
        IL_0005: dup
        IL_0006: brtrue.s IL_001f

        IL_0008: pop
        IL_0009: ldsfld class ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c' ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9'
        IL_000e: ldftn instance int32[] ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<test1>b__1_0'(int32)
        IL_0014: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]>::.ctor(object,  native int)
        IL_0019: dup
        IL_001a: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__1_0'

        IL_001f: stloc.0
        IL_0020: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__1_1'
        IL_0025: dup
        IL_0026: brtrue.s IL_003f

        IL_0028: pop
        IL_0029: ldsfld class ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c' ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9'
        IL_002e: ldftn instance int32 ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<test1>b__1_1'(int32[])
        IL_0034: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32>::.ctor(object,  native int)
        IL_0039: dup
        IL_003a: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32> ConsoleApp1.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__1_1'

        IL_003f: ldloc.0
        IL_0040: ldarg.0
        IL_0041: callvirt instance int32[] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]>::Invoke(!0)
        IL_0046: stloc.1
        IL_0047: ldloc.1
        IL_0048: callvirt instance int32 class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32>::Invoke(!0)
        IL_004d: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static int32 test2 (
            int32 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call int32[] ConsoleApp1.Program::'<test2>g__digits2_0'(int32)
        IL_0006: call int32 ConsoleApp1.Program::'<test2>g__digitSquareSum2_1'(int32[])
        IL_000b: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static int32 test3 (
            int32 'value',
            class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]> getDigits,
            class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32> getDigitSquareSum
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .locals init (
            [0] int32[] a
        )

        IL_0000: ldarg.1
        IL_0001: ldarg.0
        IL_0002: callvirt instance int32[] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32[]>::Invoke(!0)
        IL_0007: stloc.0
        IL_0008: ldarg.2
        IL_0009: ldloc.0
        IL_000a: callvirt instance int32 class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32[], int32>::Invoke(!0)
        IL_000f: ret
    }
}
```

Take a look at the IL for `test1()`. It has to new up a couple of objects and do a bunch of other stuff too.

Now look at the IL for `test3()` which uses `Func<>` parameters that are passed-in. This is a lot more efficient, but note that it still has to do a `callvirt` call to `Invoke()` on the `Func<>`.

Now look at `test2()`, which uses local functions. It just calls the function directly without needing `callvirt` or `Invoke()`. That's clearly a lot better.

However note that in all the methods, the code for the function itself is compiled only once at compile time - even for `test1()` it's not done each time `test1()` is called, so there's no overhead from that perspective.

Comment: A very thorough answer and kudos for making good use of c#7 thanks!